# Unable to start Apache Zookeeper

Tags: apache, hadoop, apache-zookeeper

I just tried to install Apache Zookeeper standalone in Ubuntu OS. I have installed Java environment and install Zookeeper 3.4.6.

However, when I typed  JPS here are only I got.

following are the configuration for bashrc and zoo.cfg file:

```
[terminal~] vim .bashrc
```

[image]

```
[terminal~]vim /usr/local/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
```

[image]

Please anyone help me. I wasted 2 days for only Zookeeper. It was really frustrated.

Comment: Any suggestions? Please!

Comment: Can't see the images

Comment: Did you see the image when you click on the link. Actually, I follow the instructions online. But I do not know what was wrong with my configuration. 
JPS just only see Jps started, and QuorumPeerMain did not start.

Comment: QuorumPeerMain did not start!!!!!!!??????????????????

Comment: what are you getting after running this command `zkServer.sh start` ??

Comment: What I got is: 
JMZ enabled by default.
Using config: /usr/local/zookeeper/bin/.../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... STARTED.

But after: jps I got only 
jps running 
No QuorumPeerMain????

Comment: try starting server with "start-foreground" to see full log of problem

zkServer.sh start-foreground

Answer (score 1):

I have a fresh installed Ubuntu machine, and this is what I did to get ZooKeeper working as a standalone program (I assume you mean that you didn't install it with the package manager.)

Download ZooKeeper tar. (I used [3.4.8](http://apache.mirrors.spacedump.net/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.8/))

Extract the folder zookeeper-3.4.8 somewhere. (I placed it on my desktop for now)

Copy .../zookeeper-3.4.8/conf/zoo_sample.cfg to /zookeeper-3.4.8/conf/zoo.cfg

And change the dataDir=... line to whatever you want. (I made a data dir inside the zookeeper-3.4.8 folder)

Now you can run zookeeper by executing the script `../zookeeper-3.4.8/bin/zkServer.sh start`

```
foo@bar:~$ /home/foo/Desktop/zookeeper-3.4.8/bin/zkServer.sh start
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /home/foo/Desktop/zookeeper-3.4.8/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... STARTED
foo@bar:~$ /home/foo/Desktop/zookeeper-3.4.8/bin/zkServer.sh status
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /home/foo/Desktop/zookeeper-3.4.8/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Mode: standalone
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I also got the same result. But how to start QuorumPeerMain? Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say that QuorumPeerMain did not start...
Is it somewhat similar to this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484398/starting-zookeeper-cluster-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-apache

Comment: Dear Petter, I really appreciate your kindly support. But I have tried 2 days (many times) to do that but I can not get the expected result. Let see: 
when we check: jps 
xxxx Jps 
xxxx QuorumPeerMain 
But I got only: xxxx Jps.

Comment: And if you look in the `zookeeper.out` file that appears when you run the start command, is there any errors in there?

Comment: After I run zkServer.sh start I get this with jps:

$jps
8689 QuorumPeerMain
8817 Jps